# Which is the best processor recommended for Windows 2008 Server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

Im developing a Web application which involves heavy usage of Parallel Task Library adhering to the best practices.It implies i need multiple processors.So which one would you recommend in terms of configuration?

Comment: File as "Not a real question"...?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing like enough details to tell. Is this a small number of CPU heavy tasks, a large number of CPU light tasks or tasks were the tasks will block (e.g. for IO)?

If there is a lot of IO used then the disk system will be more significant (look at RAID, SSDs and even SAN). If a lot of data is involved then memory bandwidth and amount might be more significant (and small code changes can have a big impact, e.g. considering the size of cache lines) so needing to focus on that aspect of motherboard and CPU design.

Overall you have two options:

- Spend your budget on what seems best (given the kind of considerations above).
- Borrow/rent a number of differently configured servers and benchmark, and then make your choice.

This is not going to be a simple answer, small changes can have a disproportionate effect. For a set of tasks that can make use of most of a modern CPUs cache (ad thus avoiding halts to wait on main RAM) a single fast core could complete tasks sequentially faster than multiple cores in parallel as it can make use of all the CPU die's cache without contention.